# Nested routes causing data reload/replacement?

Tags: ember.js

Posted this on the emberjs forums, but SO seems more appropriate.

Hi! I have two routes called classyears and classyear. They're nested like so:

```
this.resource('classyears', function(){
    this.resource('classyear', { path: '/classyear/:classyear_id'});
});

Posterkiosk.ClassyearsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Posterkiosk.Classyear.find();
  }
});

Posterkiosk.ClassyearRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(model) {
    return Posterkiosk.Classyear.find(model.classyear_id);
  }
});
```

My templates are:

Classyears:

```
<div class="yearList">
{{#each item in model}}
    {{#linkTo 'classyear' item}}{{item.id}}{{/linkTo}}
{{/each}}
</div>
{{outlet}}
```

Classyear:

```
<div class="transformContainer">
    {{trigger sizeComposites}}
    {{name}}
    {{#each students}}
      {{partial student}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

(The "trigger" helper is from another SO post. The issue was happening prior to adding it, though)

I'm using the Ember-model RESTAdapter. When I load /classyear/:classyear_id, it looks like classyear is rendering its data twice. Once with the correctly-loaded data, and once with no data loaded. The order appears to be random. If the no-data option happens last, it wipes out the correctly-loaded data, leaving a blank page. Vice-versa, and the page content displays just fine.

Any thoughts?

/edit 2: More info:

It looks as though the 0-record reply is from classyears loading. So, it's likely that the zero-record reply is actually just zero records in my hasMany field "students".

If I load /classyears (no class year specified), it only loads once, to get the class year options. If I then click on a class year, it doesn't reload classyears unless I refresh the page, at which time, it loads both, and if the classyears load (a findall) finishes second, it displays no data on the page (other than the classyears template, correctly populated, at the top).

So... maybe my classyears model isn't handling the hasMany field correctly?

I feel like I'm getting closer, but still not sure what's up.

Comment: can you add your classyears template to your question?

Comment: Edited to add both templates.

Comment: this is a little old, but might have some helpful info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246586/ember-data-sideloaded-properties-being-dropped-on-a-model

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to specify a model for a `Student`, like so:

```
Posterkiosk.Student = Ember.Model.extend({
  id: Ember.attr(),
  name: Ember.attr(),
  imageUrl: Ember.attr(),
  gradyear: Ember.attr()
});

Posterkiosk.Student.adapter = fixtureAdapter;
```

Now, in your example you are setting the key for the has many to `students`, but `students` is an array of objects, not id's, so create a property called `student_ids`, and pass an array of ids, now that is your key.

```
Posterkiosk.Classyear = Ember.Model.extend({
  students: Ember.hasMany('Posterkiosk.Student', {key: 'student_ids'})
});
```

If you set `embedded: true`, then your Classyears server response should come back like this:

```
{
  classyears: [
    {..},
    {..}
  ],
  students: [
    {..},
    {..}
  ]
}
```

Otherwise, EM would make a separate call to the endpoint on the `Student` model, and get that data based on the `student_ids` property.

See the working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/EqovAjo/2/edit?html,js,output).

Tip: RC.7+ removed the underscore from partials, plus the partial name should be in quotes..

Comment: I do actually have a model specified for Student. Almost identical to yours, but I'm including a "belongsTo" (to go with the hasMany on Classyear). 

Now, let me see if I understand the rest:

Right now, I have the student data embedded in the classyear response, so each classyear json object has an ID of the year, and a "students" property containing an array of student objects. Is that why it's pulling the data twice (or trying twice and succeeding once)?

Comment: If my answer helped solve your question, I'd appreciate it if you would accept it :)